# [Swift._NSContiguousString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, macos, encryption, foundation

I'm working on Xcode version 7.1 (7B91b), I'm using Swift and building an OSX application (10.11.2). I'm trying to generate and store RSA key pairs to be used for data encryption / decryption. Here's the implementation that has been taken from: '[AsymmetricCrypto Github](https://github.com/DigitalLeaves/AsymmetricCrypto)

```
// Constants
private let kAsymmetricCryptoManagerApplicationTag = "com.AsymmetricCrypto.keypair"
private let kAsymmetricCryptoManagerKeyType = kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA
private let kAsymmetricCryptoManagerKeySize = 2048
private let kAsymmetricCryptoManagerCypheredBufferSize = 1024
private let kAsymmetricCryptoManagerSecPadding: SecPadding = .PKCS1

func createSecureKeyPair(completion: ((success: Bool, error: AsymmetricCryptoException?) -> Void)? = nil) {
    // private key parameters
    let privateKeyParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: kAsymmetricCryptoManagerApplicationTag
    ]

    // private key parameters
    let publicKeyParams: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrIsPermanent as String: false,
        kSecAttrApplicationTag as String: kAsymmetricCryptoManagerApplicationTag
    ]

    // global parameters for our key generation
    let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
        kSecAttrKeyType as String:          kAsymmetricCryptoManagerKeyType,
        kSecAttrKeySizeInBits as String:    kAsymmetricCryptoManagerKeySize,
        kSecPublicKeyAttrs as String:       publicKeyParams,
        kSecPrivateKeyAttrs as String:      privateKeyParams,
    ]

    // asynchronously generate the key pair and call the completion block
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) { () -> Void in
        var pubKey, privKey: SecKeyRef?
        let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(parameters, &pubKey, &privKey)

        if status == errSecSuccess {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { completion?(success: true, error: nil) })
        } else {
            var error = AsymmetricCryptoException.UnknownError
            switch (status) {
            case errSecDuplicateItem: error = .DuplicateFoundWhileTryingToCreateKey
            case errSecItemNotFound: error = .KeyNotFound
            case errSecAuthFailed: error = .AuthFailed
            default: break
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { completion?(success: false, error: error) })
        }
    }
}
```

Upon calling the `createSecureKeyPair()`, as follows:

```
AsymmetricCryptoManager.sharedInstance.createSecureKeyPair({
    (success, error) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            print("keys created")
        } else {
            print("error: \(error)")
        }
    })
```

I get this error:

```
2015-12-26 03:55:46.113 sectest[17165:20928431] -[Swift._NSContiguousString bytes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x610000045880
```

and of course, the exception `AsymmetricCryptoException.UnknownError` is returned (meaning that the error is of an unknown nature), plus if it helps, `SecKeyGeneratePair()` returns the value `-2070`

The weird part is that the keys (public and private) are actually created in the Keychain as such:

[image: Keys generated in the keychain from the code above]

What is this error and how can get the expected behavior out of the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer to the problem from the Apple Developer Forums. The problem is with:

```
private let kAsymmetricCryptoManagerApplicationTag = "com.AsymmetricCrypto.keypair"
```

The values for key kSecAttrApplicationTag of params dictionaries need to be a CFDataRef, not String. The below line, resolves the problem.

```
private let kAsymmetricCryptoManagerApplicationTag = "com.sectest.keypair".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```